# Getting a screen name from a tweet search in Twython

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I am trying to pull the screen name of someone Who has tweeted about a certain keyword.
I have been able to retweet using the twitter.search function so I know thats working.

I get the following error from the bellow code

NameError: name 'screen_name' is not defined

```
search_results = twitter.search(q="keyword", count=10)
#print(search_results)
try:
    for tweet in search_results["statuses"]:
        screenname = "@" + tweet[screen_name]
        print(screenname)

except TwythonError as e:
    print ("Error: " + e)
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Official Documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/tweets), there is a `user` attribute for every tweet that contains information about the actual user who posted that tweet. The user object has a `screen_name` attribute. So I think something like this should work in your case :

```
   screenname = "@" + tweet['user']['screen_name'];
```

*Sidenote* - For debugging purposes and generally getting a hang of the `Twython` API, you might just want to print a tweet generated out of the array you're fetching to better understand all the attributes that are getting returned. That way you'll be able to point out very clearly what information you're looking for and how to fetch it.

Hope it gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly. I have been printing various variables and such at each stage to make sure I am getting the information I expect.